# Different action method depending on parameter value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two urls like this,

```
/products/home?subcat=abc
/products/home?subcat=xyz
```

I would like to have two action methods in products controller - homeabc, and homexyz.

How can I construct the route so it goes to the correct action method, depending on the value of the 'subcat' parameter?

PS: I don't have the freedom to change the url format, it has to stay the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot change the URL formats and you only have one or two, the easiest way would be to do some type of switch in the Home/Index method

```
public ActionResult Index(string subcat){
  switch(subcat.ToLower())[
      case "abc":
         return RedirectToAction("abc");
      case "xyz":
         return RedirectToAction("xyz");
      default:
         return RedirectToAction("UnknownCategory", "Errors");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the routing engine does not allow you to route based on query string parameters (`?`).  The only other possibility would be a url rewrite.